# Python Find the sum of at least 2 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, sum

If I have a list of numbers, for example `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, how do I get a dictionary of two or more numbers and the sum of these numbers? The ideal dictionary that I am looking for looks like this:

```
num = [1, 2, 3]
ideal_dict = {[1,2]:3, [1, 3]:4, [1, 4]:5, [2, 3]:5, [2, 4]:6, [3, 4]:7, [1, 2, 3]:6, [2, 3, 4]:9, [1, 2, 3, 4]:10}
```

I would like your method to work with very large numbers which are not in sequence. "not in sequence" means not all the numbers are consequent. An example of a not in sequence list is `[5, 3, 4, 8, 9]`.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. You are expected to show your existing attempt to solve the problem, and explain specifically where you got stuck. For example, can you write code to, given one of the keys for the `ideal_dict`, calculate the value? Can you write code to create combinations of a specific number of values from `num`? Can you write code to use those combinations to populate `ideal_dict`? Can you write code to repeat that process for each count of values (from 2 up to the total length of `num`)? Can you put those steps together? What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved using some of the logic of [itertools recipes (powerset function)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: If this actually answers OP's question, then the question is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for? This has two for loops, one imbedded in the other, which go through the list and adds the numbers then adds to the dictionary.

```
# original number list
numbers = (1,3,24,53,3565,474,23,2,546,27,578, 76,976)

# target dictonary
dict = {}

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    for j in range(len(numbers)):
        value = numbers[i] + numbers[j]
        dict[(i,j)] = value


print(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools' combinations, as shown below:

```
from itertools import combinations
  
def combo(arr, r):
    return list(combinations(arr, r))

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
r = [2, 3, 4]
for rr in r:
    print (combo(arr, rr))
```

OUT:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```